# How to link a library file under C++?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use a open source library under  C++.

The README file states that

> You need to link your program with `svm.cpp'.

I am wondering how to link my program with svm.cpp? Do I need to modify the make file to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile `svm.cpp` with not linking, will result `svn.o` object file, use it object file with your program linking.

Comment: I compiled and got the following error message:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to compile with the `-c` flag to generate the object file.